# How to handle dataframes with multiindexed columns in R?

Tags: r, xts

Say I want to study daily time series concerning the volumes and prices of 3 production sites: I have 6 time series that I can store as an XTS object with columns
`s1.volume, s1.price, s2.volume, s2.price, s3.volume, s3.price`

I have not found any multindexed structure similar to [what I am used to use in Python Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html).

So I use the following approaches to handle my data:

```
library(xts)
library(dygraphs)

# Example of original time series
dates <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2017-01-01"),
             to = as.POSIXct("2017-12-31"),
             by = "day")
N <- length(dates)
data <- data.frame(s1.volume = rnorm(N, 8, 1),
                 s2.volume = rnorm(N, 10, 1),
                 s3.volume = rnorm(N, 12, 1),
                 s1.price = rnorm(N, 110, 10),
                 s2.price = rnorm(N, 100, 10),
                 s3.price = rnorm(N, 90, 10))
tst_xts <- as.xts(data, order.by = dates)

# Example of manipulation to add a new calculated column for each site
sites <- c("s1", "s2", "s3")
volume_cols <- paste(sites, "volume", sep = ".")
price_cols <- paste(sites, "price", sep = ".")
mult_cols <- paste(sites, "mult", sep = ".")
mult_data <- tst_xts[ , volume_cols] * tst_xts[ , price_cols]
colnames(mult_data) <- mult_cols
tst_xts <- merge(tst_xts, mult_data)

# Function to select columns based on "multiindexing" relying on column names
sel_cols <- function(df, indexes, split = "[.]"){
  cols <- colnames(df)
  cols_split <- strsplit(cols, split)
  cols_res <- do.call(rbind, cols_split)
  is_col_sel <- rep(T, length(cols))
  for (i in 1:length(indexes)){
    index <- indexes[i]
    if (index == "") next()
    is_col_sel <- is_col_sel & (cols_res[, i] == index)
  }
  return(is_col_sel)
}

# Example to rescale prices
sel <- sel_cols(tst_xts, c("", "price"))
tst_xts[ , sel] <- tst_xts[ , sel] / 10

# Example to plot all variables for site s1
sel <- sel_cols(tst_xts, c("s1"))
dygraph(tst_xts[ , sel])
```

This 2 levels index example is quite simple but I often have to handle datasets with 4 levels of indexing.

I find all this quite tedious and would like to know if there exist cleverer structures to handle this kind of multiindexed data in R.

Comment: I guess you want `lapply(split(colnames(tst_xts), sub(".*\\.", "", colnames(tst_xts))), function(x)  tst_xts[,x])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you only want to be able to access either all s1 columns, all s2 columns, all s3 columns or all volume columns, all price columns or all mult columns.

In that case define `a` such that the volume/price/mult and s1/s2/s3 are the last two dimensions of a 3d array:

```
ix <- c(matrix(1:9, 3, byrow = TRUE))
dmn <- list(NULL, c("volume", "price", "mult"), c("s1", "s2", "s3"))
a <- array(tst_xts[, ix], c(nrow(tst_xts), 3, 3), dmn)
```

Now that we have `a` we can extract slices of it and, if need be, convert that to xts:

```
vol <- xts(a[, "volume", ], time(tst_xts))
```

and the s1 columns are:

```
s1 <- xts(a[,, "s1"], time(tst_xts))
```

etc. or to, say, multply volumes by 10:

```
a[, "volume", ] <- 10 * a[, "volume", ]
```

and then create an xts object from the volumes as shown, if need be.